# FOR loop doesn't execute properly

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm running into an odd issue with a batch file.  I want to run the following commands on a set of servers using a FOR loop.  The list of servers is -

server1
server2
server3
server4
in file "servers.txt" which is in the same folder as the batch file.  The batch file is -

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (servers.txt) do (  
net use y: /delete  
net use y: \\%%a\d$  
if exist "y:\Program Files\%%a\file.txt" goto STAGE  
echo Does not exist for %%a  
goto END  

:STAGE  
echo Exists for %%a  

:END  
net use y: /delete  
)
```

The resulting output is -

```
H:\>for /F "delims=" %a in (servers.txt) do (  
net use y: /delete  
 net use y: \\%a\d$  
 if exist "y:\Program Files\%a\file.txt" goto STAGE  
 echo Does not exist for %a  
 goto END  
 echo Exists for %a  
 net use y: /delete  
)  

H:\>(   
net use y: /delete  
 net use y: \\server1\d$  
 if exist "y:\Program Files\server1\file.txt" goto STAGE  
 echo Does not exist for server1  
 goto END  
 echo Exists for server1  
 net use y: /delete  
)  

The network connection could not be found.    
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.
```

The command completed successfully.

```
H:\>echo Exists for %a  
Exists for %a  

H:\>net use y: /delete  
y: was deleted successfully.
```

It seems to only pick up the first entry from the txt file and even then does not execute properly.  It worked fine without the FOR loop when I used a %1 parameter in place of the %%A one and executed with the servername after the batch command on a one by one basis.  Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `GOTO` always terminates all FOR-loops or leaves all blocks.
Independent of the position of the label.

So the `GOTO` has to be replaced by an `IF .. ELSE` statement.

So your code could be changed to something like

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (servers.txt) do (  
  net use y: /delete  
  net use y: \\%%a\d$  
  if exist "y:\Program Files\%%a\file.txt" (
    echo Exists for %%a  
    net use y: /delete  
  ) ELSE (
    echo Does not exist for %%a  
  )
)
```